# JavascriptExecutor: setAttribute using name

Tags: javascript, java, html, selenium-webdriver

HTML that I want to manipulate using `JavascriptExecutor` doesn't have `id`. It only contains `name`, `class` and `tag`. Out of these only `name` is unique and rest two are common for many other WebElements present in DOM.

**I tried:**

```
String javaScriptCode = "document.getElementsByName('ac118672').setAttribute('value','00031454476543');";

jse().executeScript(javaScriptCode);
```

this gave me error
`document.getElementsByName(...).setAttribute is not a function` which is obvious because `document.getElementsByName` give collection of all elements as described here https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbyname.asp.

So is there any other way I can change value of `value` attribute using JavascriptExecutor?

References I took:

[How to edit HTML (remove readonly) and type in input box using JS Executor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50105198/how-to-edit-html-remove-readonly-and-type-in-input-box-using-js-executor)

[JavaScriptexecutor setAttribute value on selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439570/javascriptexecutor-setattribute-value-on-selenium)

Answer (score 1):

After trying many ways, sleeps before and after, it wasn't working.

Finally what worked for me is:

`document.getElementsByName('ac118672')[0].value='00031454476543';`

i.e. `jse().executeScript(document.getElementsByName('ac118672')[0].value='00031454476543');`

I guess `setAttribute` also does same thing, but it didn't work.

I tested it on both Chrome and Gecko Driver latest versions, on Windows 7.

Comment: here is the difference between setAttribute and direct set value https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151560/what-is-happening-behind-setattribute-vs-attribute

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByName` returns an array of element , in your case if you have just one element with the name 'ac118672' you should access it with

`document.getElementsByName('ac118672')[0].setAttribute`

that should work

Comment: it didn't change the value, neither gave any error.

Comment: you need then to find the right attribute holding your value