# element not interactable for the Gmail password field Selenium WebDriver using java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, gmail

I'm currently trying to log in to my test Gmail box. The login is ok but for the password field I always get an:

> ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable.

I used different `xpath's` / `id's` (they are quite explicit) but it was not helpful.
The code is simple:

```
public class OpenGmail {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.setProperty ("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Chromedriver\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver wd = new ChromeDriver();
        try {
            wd.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/1pq68r75kzvdr/?v%3Dlui");
            wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='email']")).sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
            wd.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();
//Variant1
            wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@type='password']")).sendKeys("qwerty123");
//Variant2
           wd.findElement(By.id("password")).sendKeys("qwerty123");


            System.out.println("clicked");
            wd.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@class='whsOnd zHQkBf']")).sendKeys("qwerty123");
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to analyze the html and there is `aria-hidden="true"` in the `WebElement`:

```
<input type="password" class="whsOnd zHQkBf" jsname="YPqjbf" autocomplete="current-password" spellcheck="false" tabindex="0" aria-label="Enter your password" name="password" autocapitalize="off" dir="ltr" data-initial-dir="ltr" data-initial-value="">
<div jsname="YRMmle" class="AxOyFc snByac" aria-hidden="true">Enter your password</div>
```

Do I understand right that the `WebElement` is considered hidden by `WebDriver`?

Is it possible to send data to this field by JS, for example? I wanted to try setAttribute [JavaScriptexecutor setAttribute value on selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42439570/javascriptexecutor-setattribute-value-on-selenium) but I've never used JS before.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the time to read [ask]. It will help you craft solid questions that will hopefully get useful answers.  FWIW: gmail is notoriously difficult to automate via webdriver; consider using the gmail API.  YMMV.

Comment: Thanks! I will form my future questions more in line to the How to.
I am trying to master the API also but for today the answer from @frianH is more handy for my purpose.

Comment: Very good.  Here's an upvote :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For password input you mean in gmail sign in pages, you can use this locator: `By.name("password")` and it seem like you need wait this element. First, following import:

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
```

And try the bellow code:

```
wd.get("https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/h/1pq68r75kzvdr/?v%3Dlui");

//wait email input
WebElement email = new WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("identifier")));
email.sendKeys("test@gmail.com");
wd.findElement(By.id("identifierNext")).click();

//wait password input
WebElement password = new WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.name("password")));
password.sendKeys("qwerty123");
System.out.println("clicked");
```